# Probability Distribution with sense of "direction"

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, density-function

Warning: this is a vague question.

Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a direction and suppose I would like to find a distribution that puts *considerable* mass along $v$. Is there any such "directional" distribution?

One example is that if I have $x\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)$ then I can compute
$$
x + \gamma \hat{v}\hat{v}^\top x \sim N(0, AA^\top)\qquad\qquad A=(I + \gamma\hat{v}\hat{v}^\top)
$$
which turns out to have variance $1 + \gamma$ in the direction of $\hat{v}$ and $1$ in the direction of any vector $w\perp v$. This means that for large $\gamma$ I can indeed put more pass along this direction. Are there other examples?

## Visualization

The distribution I have described above, for instance, will look like this:

[image]

Comment: The linked page introduces some directional distributions such as different wrapped and circular distributions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics

Comment: @jros Thank you. To me that looks quite different from what I am trying to do. Those wrapped distributions are on a circle/sphere meaning that if they follow a direction, that is the tangent direction, which keeps changing. In contrast, what I am looking for is a distribution that puts mass on a fixed arbitrary direction $v$.

Comment: There is a huge set of possibilities -- so consider explaining why you want to do this and what your constraints might be.  After all, you can take literally *any* distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and apply a linear transformation.  This will stretch the density differentially in various directions.  By choosing $v$ to be an eigenvector with a relatively large eigenvalue, you have your result.  Conversely, *every* distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be created in such a way.